# Inicializar un arreglo tipo C a partir de un std::array

Tags: c++, array

En C++ tengo algunos archivos escritos en C.
En uno de ellos se define esta estructura al estilo de C.
Es código muy antiguo y que no puedo modificar.

```cpp
struct Punto {
   double coordenadas[3];
};
```

Por otro lado tengo una función más moderna que, en vez de arreglos clásicos, devuelve un objeto [`std::array`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```cpp
std::array<double, 3> CalcularPunto();
```

Si quiero inicializar un `Punto` a partir del valor de retorno de mi función hago lo siguiente:

```cpp
Punto ans;
std::array<double, 3> ansArray{CalcularPunto()};
std::copy(ansArray.begin(), ansArray.end(), ans.coordenadas);
```

Cuando quiero hacer la conversión contraria puedo usar [`std::to_array`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array).
¿Hay alguna forma de declarar e inicializar `Punto` en una sola línea con el valor de retorno de `CalcularPunto()`?

Teniendo sólo 3 coordenadas puedo hacer:

```cpp
Punto ans{ansArray[0], ansArray[1], ansArray[2]};
```

Pero si quisiera templatizar esta incialización, no sabría cómo hacerlo.

Comment: ¿ Ves como me patina ? No leí lo de `antiguo y que no puedo modificar`.

Comment: Los constructores, el operador de asignación y las conversiones solo pueden declararse dentro de la clase. ¿Por qué no podrías modificar esa estructura?

Comment: Se me ocurre que crees una clase `MyPunto` que tenga una variable-miembro de tipo `Punto`. A partir de ahí, puedes jugar con tus constructores y con los operadores de conversión definidos por el usuario. Recuerdo haber utilizado algo así en alguna ocasión. Aunque depende de que las variables-miembro de `Punto` sean públicas o al menos protegidas.

Comment: @Mateo La estructura `Punto`se sigue usando en librerías que se compilan en C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi respuesta está basada en [una repuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77684039/12575557) de [Jan Schultke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740428/jan-schultke) en Stack Overflow: [How to generalize conversion from std::array to struct with raw array member in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77683936/)

Usaremos la función [`std::apply`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) para expandir los elementos del arreglo que devuelve `CalcularPunto`.
El segundo argumento de `std::apply` es un objeto que soporte [`std::get`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) y [`std::tuple_size`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_size) ([similar a una tupla](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple-like)).
Esto incluye `std::pair` o `std::array`.
El primer argumento debe ser una función cuyos argumentos sean los elementos de nuestra tupla.
Esto se puede conseguir con una función [template variádica](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic).
Dentro de la función expandiremos el [paquete de parámetros](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) para utilizarlos como argumentos en el [incializador](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) de `Punto`:

```cpp
auto inicializaPunto = [](auto... coordenadas) { return Punto{coordenadas...}; };
```

Uno podría tener la tentación de escribir `inicializaPunto` como una template en vez de una función lambda.
Sin embargo, en la pregunta [Why does std::apply fail with function template, but not with a lambda expression with explicit template parameter list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696245) se explica que el segundo argumento de `std::apply` necesita ser llamable, y una template cuyos argumentos aún no se han resuelto no lo es.

Ahora basta con pasar los elementos del arreglo a esta función lambda con `std::apply`:

```cpp
Punto p = std::apply(inicializaPunto, CalcularPunto());
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Qué tal si creas una clase nueva como dice Trauma? Puedes crear los [constructores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), [operadores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) y [conversiones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) que sean necesarias. Por ejemplo:

```
class Point {
    std::array<double, 3> coordenadas;

public:
    Point(const std::array<double, 3>& coordenadas){
        this->coordenadas = coordenadas;
    }

    Point& operator=(const std::array<double, 3>& coordenadas){
        this->coordenadas = coordenadas;
        return *this;
    }

    operator Punto() const {
        return {coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1], coordenadas[2]};
    }
};
```

Aunque no puedes asignar directamente la función a una variable `Punto`:

```
// error
Punto p = CalcularPunto();
```

Sí puedes asignar directamente la variable del nuevo tipo:

```
// La primera vez llama implícitamente al constructor
Point p = CalcularPunto();
```

---

Otra opción sencilla aunque [no recomendable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970/13419694) es crear una unión aprovechando que comparten la misma disposición en memoria:

```
union P {
    std::array<double, 3> arr;
    Punto punto;
};

P p3;
p3.arr = CalcularPunto();
```

Answer (score 1):

ya tienes, como dices, una función `std::to_array` simplemente te falta la conversión en sentido opuesto, es decir, de `std::array` a tu estructura `Punto` :

```
Punto to_punto(std::array<double, 3> const& array)
{
    Punto point;
    std::copy(ansArray.begin(), ansArray.end(), point.coordenadas);
    return point;
}
```

Con la función ya puedes hacer la conversión en una sola línea:

```
Punto ans = to_punto(CalcularPunto());
```

Piensa que la función `std::to_array` no hace ninguna magia, simplemente deduce cómo debe copiar la información para poder generar el objeto que tu esperas.

Comment: En `to_punto` hay algún motivo para preferir `std::copy` antes que `return {ansArray[0], ansArray[1], ansArray[2]}`?

Comment: @JorgeLuis en esencia va a ser lo mismo. Piensa que luego el compilador realizará optimizaciones sobre el código que pongas. Si el rendimiento es algo crítico entonces ya tendrás que mirar qué opción es la que más te conviene en cada caso

Comment: @JorgeLuis hasta podrías hacer la maldad: `(Punto*)array.data()` para tratar al `array` como `Punto` pero no funcionaría bien si el compilador pusiera padding a `Punto`. Cómo mínimo `sizeof(Punto)` debe ser igual a `sizeof(Punto:: coordenadas)`.

Answer (score -2):

Puedes crear una función de conversión:

```cpp
template <typename result_t, typename type_t, auto size>
result_t convierte_a(const std::array<type_t, size> &array)
{
    auto convertir = [&array]<std::size_t ... index_pack>(const std::index_sequence<index_pack ...> &) -> result_t
    {
        return {array[index_pack] ...};
    };

    return convertir(std::make_index_sequence<3>{});
}
```

Que puede usarse así:

```cpp
auto p = convierte_a<Punto>(CalcularPunto());
```

Y al ser una plantilla, puedes usar tipos de punto arbitrarios:

```
template <typename type_t, auto size>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const PuntoX<type_t, size> &p)
{
    for (const auto &c : p.coordenadas)
        o << c << ' ';

    return o;
}

int main()
{
    auto pf3 = convierte_a<PuntoX<float, 4>>(CalcularPunto<float, 4>());
    auto pld15 = convierte_a<PuntoX<long double, 15>>(CalcularPunto<long double, 15>());

    std::cout << pf3 << '\n';   // Punto de 3 double.
    std::cout << pld15 << '\n'; // Punto de 15 long double.

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzNIADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxtpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BflzllWk1dQQFYZHRcdIKtfWNWS2Dnd1FJf0AlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxbnXETACee9gmGgCCaxtbmLv7ToPEmKxnF9dXz14O28peglQuwA7BZtugFhF6Ns0CQsMx0EwFCYAKwWWKogAiezBJmB2NiViuHwImBYCQMpIebgIxwSjFY91p9IA%2BgRSNsmF4iNsUgAvTDvL4EYg/Ah/AFEAAaILBzMwbJhqDhDMRyLR/MFKIJuPxOI%2BJLJFKYVL2NLpDLY23lbI5XJ5mqFl0G6BAIEOJzNNvZvLwArO2wOtGQXgMxH%2BgIgMwNoI%2B23j2xeBEWDF2aKxZpdbs1ioAdPntsEsKoWQkmMgANZnCBoBiDXkEV0gIuYEtKACOXkYyzNLZLZcr23zuYD5gAbDNtgBaANZ93EI6nfbejmO2LnK4J2UGjQATi3SZTsr7pfLFaH%2BbxOrjCavEDnLCYFYVJ47XYYPf2a/Osfx0cJMbYsSVykuSlL3F6FrMFaLwKKGBC2taUGMkhrI%2BvaQLfh8sHwYqtYAG54NEpIskwNYCPWc4eku5poaufqCuuuxmGO1HRsSsabgmGFKgw%2BHEXgxAPJiaZWCx1EZl%2BjbZgxeYFieA5Vuu5F1uKc6vpgnbdoxbgKWeF4jkx46TjOTE4bQCEEDe8Z4kSnz7gmh7EKmtkSWiemVliBlXvqXE2XqAHAZcB6YMmzm8fx9SCfe0kgI%2Bz4shpWkfjpGLrrZV7/nZPlBaBxqmsuyFWiunLcphDFOnOyQiq8LDMWOqD0kcRBCWaZoxU21UvKw9WoBytb1hG0qQXRvr%2BkZLEJOx1yccFCb8EJKn1jx47INsIDbAkuawsQ8JMGq01bluQJtfsMLUma2xgBwV2rIFnxzfGTmpqgvkzUBD3BOKj7BFGMZ2VuPEJFQsTCRFRH1AqTBmkNqBSmaVC0KgJocpI7zKUGIZhrDCNIyj2xo8pMxZdZpU8hS6BcCiYMERDJHQ/ssPw/sSNGOCkL0ByVPo9gECY6GdQ4yzAjAOzXhQpgXMotWxNvaTc5oNyF1ncDoOnW4t2om4DDXW9W4Kws4rq5ttCU9Txu6yi2u6/dO67s92waHL%2BIcHMtCcCivB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1i8gsSwQWYsQ8KQBCaK7cwIK8WAxFGpAViAKKSLmAAcwIaLEu5mGYkgaGYWdU2O%2BicJIvAsBIGgaKQ3u%2B/7HC8AoIANzHPuu6QcCwDAiAgK2mAhi15CUHUwAKMohgVEICCoAA7t7UdoOSdAmmkM8hLQ89L03vBrwkdB9FPzAJAoC/skfJ/EKEjKcIfqDr/QxAAPLcnvy%2Bx6Qw/IJcxAp6P1/qoEeNR8De14PwQQIgxDsCkDIQQigVDqG7qQXQZh9CGGMEHSw%2Bg8ARHbpAOYjUqjtw4FOF0exMSmEsNYMwEReCoEisQPAWAiEp1FIIPAbAAAqypaAcLmAoUOyw9AumCNvOeC9v7cF4IvI4CROA8Ddh7L2P8W7YFAaPEg2xVBZzHFOMckhtjAGQGtCAIoAQVknHzXBNhti4EILotYXAZi8C7loYmqcQCSBRLmLgZhdxjg0MCYEKJdzAi4FnSQ0h3YcGrqQWuKIG4Hz9sA9undY5zD7oPG%2Br9x7kRfn0OoLBgBWIYBWPgdBSTEHbhACIP8IjBDqMcZRvBmnMGIMcN%2BERtAjy7qvZ%2BbBBBvwYLQNpaCsARC8MAIMgj2mkCwI%2BIw4gpmCQGXgfi5DfZ/25CsKOX0Kg/1oAQo43SPBYB/iKHh7S5iIyYFPAAakRReb96QrygbIWB4gEHQPkEoNQP9dAtAMEYFA9j8GEPgCQhIZDOCUMbNQ2hYkLBmCYNON%2BTCWFsMwEI1omznAQFcCMZov8GDoEmL0GILQcipAEKS7IyR6UMCpcUPoYwKiEuqEMBongmjiK5Q4dovK2XTDGLyxlEqJjBB6OymlwjRHwNURwT2jcNGcG2JcAASgAWW2AAcTcBrCp54IBOJasxSO7jo7ZPjonPoKd4mJOSakjVrdbAd1td3bxac/EBKCSEsJESokxLiZwWI6i0Etw8XayuHAzBRubsAzxcdSCRRSM4SQQA%3D%3D)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias por la idea, pero no puedo modificar `Punto`.

Comment: Entonces no podrás templatizarlo @JorgeLuis

Comment: Supongo que no me expresé con claridad. No quiero templatizar `Punto`, sino la conversión de una `std::array` a una estructura cuyo único atributo una array tipo C con tantos elementos como la `std::array` original.

Comment: @JorgeLuis En ese caso, la función `convierte_a` ya te funciona, tanto con `Punto` templatizado como (como es tu caso) sin templatizar.